# Retrieve Top level Name space Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a number of name space, but I need to get the name of the top level namespace.

A::B::C

So, if I call .class, I get A::B::C, but I need it to return just the top namespace A.

Is there a method for this?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method for what you're looking for. You could do smt like `class.name.split("::").first` though. The closest built-in method would be `deconstantize`, but in your case that would return `A::B` instead of `A`

Comment: That’s what I ended up doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following nested modules:

```
module A
  module B
    module C
    end
  end
end
```

If you are given the module

```
m = A::B::C
```

then the top-level module equals:

```
top = Module.const_get(m.to_s[/.+?(?=::)/])
  #=> A 
top.is_a? Module
  #=> true
```

See [Module#const_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Module.html#method-i-const_get). The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters lazily (`?`) that are followed by two colons", `(?=::)` being a *positive lookahead*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parents` method to get the array of all parent modules.

```
module A
  module B
    module C
    end
  end
end

my_namespace = A::B::C
my_namespace.parents  # => [A::B, A, Object]
my_namespace.parents.last(2).first  # => A
```